# Can I make the website URL show only the domain, and not the file name?

Tags: dns, web, web-hosting

I have a website and have signed up with a web host. Everything is okay with it, but there is one problem. I want people to only have to type in the domain name of my website (e.g. example.com). But you have to put in the file name along with the domain (e.g. example.com/home.html). How can I upload the files to the domain name? (and make it where you don't have to type in the file name?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the `home.html` file to `index.html` and they will only have to type the domain as index is the default name your web server will look for.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! It really helped and REALLY WORKED!

Comment: The answer was easy, troublesome was to comprehend what has been asked :D Plus 1

Comment: You are welcome! You can mark it as correct answer in case other people have the same question.